# VirtualBox Windows 98 mount vbox net drive

Tags: windows, virtualbox, network-shares

I setup an working Windows 98 (first edition) installation within VirtualBox 4.1.12. Network and graphiccard works fine. But I have trouble with mounting VirtualBox net shares.

First I tried `\\vboxsvr\sharename` but Windows says it couldn't find the "object". Then I open `command` and searched for my gateway within `ipconfig`. With the IP address I tried `\\10.0.2.2\share` but the error message is the same as my first try.

Does anybody have successful mounted an VirtualBox net share within Windows 98?

Comment: I assume you need to install Guest Additions, which don't work on Win98. Try bridging the 98 VM to your network and accessing a network share, instead.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Your assumption is quite correct, you may want to post that as an answer. Note that Win98 doesn't install TCP/IP support by default, this needs to be configured after install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VirtualBox shared folders work by installing networking components into the virtual machine. These are installed as part of the Guest Additions. Guest Additions aren't available for Windows 98.

Try bridging the 98 VM to your network and accessing a network share, instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my network is working. Or do you want to try me setup a "real" network share on my host and access it within VM so there is "no VirtualBox between"?